# file name division and instantiation

Tags: foreach, tcl

```
set session_list [list ../../TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR/FUNC_ss28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_125C_RCmax/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION    ../../TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR/FUNC_ff28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_m40C_Cmin/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION ]

foreach j $session_list {
  lappend x  [regsub {^../../TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR/} $j ""]
}

foreach p $x {
   lappend y [regsub {[^...]reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION} $p ""]
}

foreach item $y {
  lappend r "create_scenario -name $item"
}

foreach term $r {
  lappend k  " $term -image ./../   "
}
```

This is the code I created, the desired result is :

```
create_scenario -name  FUNC_ss28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_125C_RCmax -image ./../FUNC_ss28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_125C_RCmax/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION        
create_scenario -name  FUNC_ff28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_m40C_Cmin -image ./../UNC_ff28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_m40C_Cmin/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION
```

How do I achieve this? My main problem is calling list"x" in the last `foreach` statement. Is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and I would even say should) use a single loop for that since you are doing the same thing for all elements of the list. From my understanding, you need to get the part after `../../TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR` to get the name and the image is the name and everything after it.

So instead of removing what's not wanted, I would rather 'capture' what's wanted like this:

```
# Just another way to have a list
set session_list {
    ../../TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR/FUNC_ss28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_125C_RCmax/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION
    ../../TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR/FUNC_ff28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_m40C_Cmin/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION
}

foreach item $session_list {
    regexp -- {TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR/(([^/]+).+)} $item -> image name
    set result "create_scenario -name $name -image ./../$image"
    puts $result
}
# Prints:
# create_scenario -name FUNC_ss28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_125C_RCmax -image ./../FUNC_ss28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_125C_RCmax/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION
# create_scenario -name FUNC_ff28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_m40C_Cmin -image ./../FUNC_ff28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_m40C_Cmin/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/xlKrdX)

In the regexp, `([^/]+)` will match and capture all characters except the forward slash character after `TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR/`. Then this, plus `.+` (in `(([^/]+).+)` gets the name, and everything else after the name since `.` matches all characters.

Now, the regex can be a bit confusing since we are first getting the image then the name, but that's because the outer parentheses comes first, then the name is inside it.

---

If you don't want to (or you find regex too hard), you might try using [`file`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm) commands instead:

```
foreach item $session_list {
    # Split on the directories
    set elements [file split $item]

    # Get the position of TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR
    set id [lsearch $elements "TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR"]

    # The name is just after it so...
    set name [lindex $elements $id+1]

    # The image is everything after the id:
    set image [file join [lrange $elements $id+1 end]]
    # Or if file join somehow is not using forward slashes:
    # set image [join [list [lrange $elements $id+1 end]] "/"]

    set result "create_scenario -name $name -image ./../$image"
}
```

<sub>Note: I am using Tcl8.6 if you are using Tcl8.4 or earlier versions, some of the syntax would have to be changed</sub>

Comment: `foreach item $session_list {
   
          regexp -- {TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR/(([^/]+).+)} $item -> image name
    

                set result "create_scenario -name $name -image ./../$image"
    
              puts $result
}`

Comment: when executing this error comes up saying **Cant read  "name":no such variable**

Comment: @Justus This means that the pattern was not matched. Do all strings in the `session_list` have `TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR`? If not, then what should be done to those?

Comment: @Justus I can put some error handling in the script if you want me to, but I need to know what you want to happen to the things that don't conform to the rules you have.

Comment: all the strings in `session_list` do have `../../TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR/` in them !!

Comment: i dont get it ,even the `split file` method isn't working too .

Comment: @Justus That's what I'm telling you. The line you are working with does not contain `TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR`. What should be done to those?

Comment: i found it .. i had added `set session_list {list`  . your code worked fine otherwise !! but i dont understand why this error .

Comment: @Justus Lol. That created a line without `TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR`, so there would be no match (hence no variable `name`) and with the file split, no element of splitting the path would match `TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR` either in `lsearch`.